# GetModuleFileNameEx - Is it possible to get the path in char* and NOT in TCHAR[]?

Tags: c++, winapi, ascii

Here is my code:

```
TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");
GetModuleFileNameEx (hProcess, NULL, szProcessName, 
                     sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR));
```

I need the path in `char*`, and not in `TCHAR[]`. Is it somehow possible without converting `(WideCharToMultiByte)`?

Thanks...

Answer (score 6):

GetModuleFileNameEx is just a macro. You could use GetModuleFileNameExA for ANSI version. It will call GetModuleFileNameExW and then internally make all conversions.

But you should make sure that module filename does not contain Unicode characters.

```
char szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = "<unknown>";
GetModuleFileNameExA(hProcess, NULL, szProcessName, sizeof szProcessName);
```

Comment: Thank, but why is it throws an error:

  //  TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");
    char* szProcessName = "<unknown>";
    GetModuleFileNameExA (hProcess, NULL, szProcessName, MAX_PATH);
printf("%s", szProcessName);

Comment: It might be easier to figure out what you are trying to say if you edit your original post ...

Comment: szProcessName should be large enough to keep MAX_PATH characters.

Comment: Unknown, you had an array at first. That was correct. When you changed the base type to `char`, you also made it a pointer instead of an array. That was wrong. Keep it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you're not building a Unicode application (i.e., _UNICODE is not defined), then TCHAR == char